# Sumar valores de un if y ver el resultado total

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo un `for` que está en Objective-C (no tengo mucha idea de ello) tengo la app en Swift. Llamo a la función y todo perfecto pero me devuelve dos valores cuando recorte la sentencia `if`.

```
2016-01-20 21:54:46.742 Prueba[3306:926796] Core: 0 Usage: 0.153268
2016-01-20 21:54:55.874 Prueba[3306:926796] Core: 1 Usage: 0.081846
```

Lo que quiero es sumar los dos valores de `Core 0` y `Core 1` y sacar el % de la suma.

El código del `for`:

```
for(unsigned i = 0U; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
        float inUse, total;
        if(prevCpuInfo) {
            inUse = (
                     (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER])
                     + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM])
                     + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE])
                     );
            total = inUse + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE]);
        } else {
            inUse = cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE];
            total = inUse + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE];
        }

        NSLog(@"Core: %u Usage: %f",i,inUse / total);
    }
```

Comment: Cuidado, que los valores que devuelve ese if son los valores por cada core, por lo que no tiene sentido sumarlos. Es decir, una CPU puede tener varios cores, y cada core tiene sus valores. En ese NSLog te esta diciendo: "el core X tiene en uso un tanto por ciento del total". Pero sumar ese resultado no tiene sentido...

Comment: si por que si sumo los valores de cada core me da % total del uso de la cpu

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el uso medio de toda la CPU, es decir, la suma de todos los cores dividido entre el número de cores modifica el código tal que así:

```
float cpuTotal; // !!!!!!!!!!!!!
for(unsigned i = 0U; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
    float inUse, total;
    if(prevCpuInfo) {
        inUse = (
                 (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER])
                 + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM])
                 + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE])
                 );
        total = inUse + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE]);
    } else {
        inUse = cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE];
        total = inUse + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE];
    }

    cpuTotal += inUse / total; // !!!!!!!!!!!!!

}
NSLog(@"CPU Core usage: %f", cpuTotal / numCPUs); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

PD: Te he marcado el código importante